# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_props$route$params$d.id')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am trying to fetch an api and get details of resources in resources detail page but getting an error of this `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_props$route$params$d.id')`

**[image]**

**data containing my api**

```
const clickedItem = (data) => {
        props.navigation.navigate("ResourceDetail", { data: data })
 }  

const renderData = (item) => {
        return (
            <Card style={styles.cardStyle} onPress={() => clickedItem()}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 17 }}>{item.docs}</Text>
            </Card>
        )
    }
```

**ResourceDetail.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

function ResourceDetail(props) {

    const { id, title, docs } = props.route.params.data;

    return (
        <Text>{title}</Text>
    )
}

export default ResourceDetail
```

Answer (score 0):

In ResourceDetail.js program can't get id from `props.route.params.data`

You called `clickedItem` without any parameter. so data is undefined.

and where is you called API?